# Is there a way to return an outer function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, closures

Let's say I have the following code:

```
function check(code){
    var result=false;
    $.each(arrayOfFunctions,function(){
        thisresult=this.call(this,code);
        if (thisresult==true){
            result=true;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

So I have a function with one input.  I have an array of functions that I apply to that data.  If any of them are true, the outer function is true.

When I'm in the inner function, is there a way to return on the outer function?  Are there any other optimizations that can be done to my code?

Comment: You may want to optimize the anonymous function to `function() { return !(result = this.call(this, code)); }`

Answer (score 3):

In jQuery, using `return false` inside [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) and [`$().each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) will stop the loop. Before stopping the loop, set a variable which will be returned.

```
function check(code){
    var result = false;
    $.each(arrayOfFunctions,function(){
        thisresult = this.call(this,code);
        if (thisresult == true){
            result=true;
            return false; // = similar to the "break" keyword in a loop
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Good point, I actually have that in my code, but I omitted it here to reduce confusion.

Comment: @Joe Considering the names and formatting, I assumed that you provided pseudo-code. If that's your real code, you should at least prefix `thisresult` by `var`. If you share more information about your code, I can optimize it. I suspect that you don't even need jQuery.